# How to rotate a ImageBox on a windows form using vb6

Tags: vb6, basic

I need to rotate a Image box 55 degrees when a condition in my if statement is met. Is this possible?

Comment: If you mean the VB6 `Image` control, no you can't rotate it.  Rotating an image displayed in it is another question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible to rotate an image by using Windows API.
Can you have a look on [Rotate Images in PictureBoxes](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=25764&lngWId=1)?